LLMs and OWL ontologies
Some authors affirm that LLMs will make OWL ontologies obsolete. However, LLMS are created by probabilistic means (I suppose) and ontologies are created by humans. Can someone provide a good reference about this discussion?

I cannot provide a reference but I have seen multiple comments of the kind "LLM are black boxes and not even their developers can explain exactly why a certain output is produced". That's not strictly true, of course, however neural networks aren't designed for human readable explanations, nor gor logical inference. Ontologies, on the other hand, are designed just for that, explanations can be produced, they have logical foundations and there are tools to work with them. A reasoner will not create a picture or generate text, thought. So, very different use cases.
